# Wordpress: how to set hook priority?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function and hook to redirect a visitor right after the registration.

It doesn't work. As far as I see the code is right, then I guess that might be other plugin using the same plugin.

**Is there a way to set the priority of my hook to override the other one?**

```
function somlaw_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}

add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'somlaw_registration_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 2):

**add_filter Format like this,**

```
add_filter( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

**For E.g.**

```
// Accepting two arguments (three possible).
function example_callback( $value, $arg2 ) {
    ...
    return $maybe_modified_value;
}
add_filter( 'hook', 'example_callback', 10, 2 ); // Where $priority is 10, $accepted_args is 2.
```

In your code, you can set the priority as like,

```
function somlaw_registration_redirect() {
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'somlaw_registration_redirect', 5, 2 );
```

**Get more details:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
function somlaw_registration_redirect() {
  return home_url( '/my-page' );
}  
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'somlaw_registration_redirect',3);
```

[add_filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) accepts the 3rd argument as priority. Default value is 10 so enter any value lower then 10 to set the priority.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'somlaw_registration_redirect', 5 );
```

The last digit 5 is the priority. Default is 10. You can lower it further and check which number works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing argument in the function alongwith setting priority :

```
function somlaw_registration_redirect( $redirect_url ) {
    return home_url( '/my-page' );
}
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'somlaw_registration_redirect', 3 );
```

Note: Also try changing the priority.